# Angular 8: Problems with QueryParamsHandling

Tags: angular, angular8, primeng

I'm trying to make a table with PrimeNG and after made the import in the module file

```
import {TableModule} from 'primeng/table';
```

I have the next error:

```
node_modules/primeng/api/megamenuitem.d.ts(30,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'QueryParamsHandling'.
node_modules/primeng/api/menuitem.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"../../@angular/router/router"' has no exported member 'QueryParamsHandling'.
```

I have searched in google and in the community and I haven't found any solutions

Please. Could anybody help me?
Many thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: What is your primeng version? And did you import in appmodule or component ?

Comment: Yees I did the import in the appmodule and the primeng version is the 9.1.0

Answer (score 3):

There is a mismatch between the Angular version and the PrimeNG version. You are using Angular 8, and PrimeNG version 7. Run the following commands

```
npm uninstall primeng
npm install primeng@8.0.1
```

Should fix it.